# Automapper Dynamic Resolver's

Tags: c#, expression, automapper, castle-dynamicproxy

I'm trying to create an abstract layer on top of automapper which enables users to dynamically add custom rules to each property they map.

Given the Model

```
public class Entity
{
    public int Index { get; set; }
}

public class DTO
{
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

we may configure Automapper to map the entities like so:

```
//sorry this is pseudo coded
cfg.CreateMap<Entity, DTO>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Index, 
        opt => opt.ResolveUsing<IndexResolver>());


public class IndexResolver: ValueResolver<DTO, int>, 
{
    protected override string ResolveCore(DTO source)
    {
        return source.Count - 1;
    }
}
```

This works since we map the rule to a Value resolver, However if I wanted to create a rule at run time is that possible.  I would like to be able to configure things like so:

```
cfg.CreateMap<Entity, DTO>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Index, 
        opt => opt.Resolver(d => d.Count - 1);
```

Is there a way I can Add a resolver with an expression so I do not need to inherit from ValueResolver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought is to create a generic custom resolver that takes an expression in its constructor.  You should then be able to do:

```
.ResolveUsing(new LambdaResolver(d => d.Count - 1))
```

Comment: How would you handle the ValueResolver for the Lambda Resolver? do you mean like this `LambdaResolver<Entity, DTO, int>`

Comment: Carefully setup an Option Manager which takes in generic lambdas and stores them in a dictionary? Then foreach expression in the Type Map Options Apply them using reflection with a LambdaResolver, and store the mappers as a singleton in my DI so I don't eat time using reflection creating a new mapper each time?

Comment: Ahh Maybe since the mapping option is type I won't need to use reflection, since I should have access to it from the map.  Interesting I'll investigate